# Why does this.datacontext (Window) show data from viewModel and FrameContent.datacontext (page) does not?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window, datacontext

Why does this.datacontext (Window) show data from viewModel and FrameContent.datacontext (page) does not?

Currently, I load the data from a page's view to the window.
Instead of loading it directly to the dataContext of the window, I want to load it in the dataContext of the frame where the data is showed.

Below my code:

ViewConfiguration.xaml:

```
<Frame x:Name="FrameContent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

ViewConfiguration.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Modules.Configuration
{
    public partial class ViewConfiguration : Window
    {
        public ViewConfiguration()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           ViewModelConfiguration ViewModelConfiguration = new ViewModelConfiguration();

        }   

        private void PageEditor1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext = new ViewModelEditor1();
            FrameContent.Source = new Uri("/Modules/Editor1/View/ViewEditor1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        }

        private void PageEditor2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext    = new ViewModelEditor2();
            FrameContent.Source = new Uri("/Modules/Editor2/View/ViewEditor2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }
}
```

I suspected that something like this would work, but does not.

```
private void PageEditor1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // this.DataContext = new ViewModelEditor1();           // loading in datacontext of window
    this.FrameContent.DataContext = new ViewModelEditor1(); // loading in datacontext of frame
    FrameContent.Source = new Uri("/Modules/Editor1/View/ViewEditor1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Adam Nathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Nathan) states in his book [WPF Unleashed](http://adamnathan.net/wpf/) (take a look to Chapter 4, "Introducing WPF's Controls"), `Frame` control is used for ***isolating*** its content from the rest of your user interface, so for this reason it does not inherit its parent's properties (`DataContext` included).

Therefore your line of code

```
this.FrameContent.DataContext = new ViewModelEditor1();
```

is *necessary* for making you application work.