# Binding to ViewModel with ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm using this `DockPanel`.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame">
        <Frame.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
                <DockPanel Margin="7">
                    <StackPanel Margin="7" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <Button Margin="5" Content="Avast! Go back!" Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" IsEnabled="False" />
                        <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding ButtonForwardtext}" Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseForward}" IsEnabled="False" Width="52" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="black" BorderThickness="2" Padding="7" CornerRadius="4">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="90" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,10,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="New Page!" Command="{Binding FwdText, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Padding="7" CornerRadius="4">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Frame.Template>
    </Frame>
</DockPanel>
```

I have the data context successfully hooked up, but when I try to bind the text of the button to a property in the ViewModel (for testing purposes) for whatever reason, it does not work. If I bind the ViewModel outside of the `DockPanel`, it works fine.

Anyone know the proper way to bind to the ViewModel inside a ControlTemplate? I've tried TemplateBinding, still doesn't like it.

Comment: Are there any binding errors in your output window when you run your app with the debugger attached? That is usually where I find out what is going wrong when I have these types of issues.

Comment: If there are no binding errors then use a Debug converter to see what is your data context is coming as.

Comment: Try to give a look to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39207839/4377809) of mine, probably it can help you with your issue